# Pytest run by test explorer of vscode does not find modules installed by pip in dev mode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pip, pytest

Running tests on my project code installed with `pip` in developer mode (`pip install -e .`) does work by executing `pytest` from the command line. However, running the same tests within the same Python `virtualenv` using the Test Explorer UI of Visual Studio Code does not work, Python raises `ModuleNotFoundError`s.

I confirmed that my package is installed by `pip list -v`, which prints:

```
myproject            0.0.0      /path/to/myproject
```

Furthermore, I wrote failing test to get the Python path during test execution:

```
import sys


def test_some_test():
    print(sys.executable)
    print(sys.path)

    assert False
```

This confirms that the Python executable is the one from the `virtualenv` where my project code is installed. But the `sys.path` differs between the Test Explorer run and the command line run. The Test Explorer run does not include the `/path/to/myproject` in the `sys.path`, whereas the command line run does. Obviously, if the project's path is included in the `sys.path`, the package can be imported. Why is it missing from the Test Explorer UI run? How to make the Test Explorer use the packages installed in develop mode with `pip`?

I should add that the modules I try to import in my tests are in a package themselves, called `mylib`. So the actual import in my test is like

```
from mylib import function_under_test


def test_function_under_test():
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

This issue is fixed now. It just works.

## Old Answer

Fiddling around with the issue more, I found that this is a bug in the Python extension for vscode, cf. issues
[14579](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14579), and [14570](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14570) on github.com.

As a work-around one may either install the Little Fox Team [Test Explorer UI extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=LittleFoxTeam.vscode-python-test-adapter), or an old version of the Microsoft Python extension (v2020.9.114305).